# yii load CRUD elements somewhere else

Tags: php, yii

I have got a products database, and in that database i want to add products. But now i want only the admin to be able to add products, and made a folder `admin/index.php`

On this index.php i tried to run:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

Stolen from `products/create.php`. But that did not work. So i tried:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>'products')); ?>
```

Because the model is called products, but also that did not work.

How can i load models in other pages? Please help i'm totally new to Yii!

Comment: that is the correct way... `var_dump($model)` and check that it is initialized

Comment: Did you pass the `$model` variable from controller to `index.php` during `render`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to use a view from another model, assuming you're looking to render `/protected/views/products/_form.php`:

```
$this->renderPartial('application.views.products._form',
    array(
        ...
    )
);
```

However, the correct way to do this surely is to restrict the admin user to be the only user to be able to access the `mysite.com/products/admin` route? If you're using Gii, this will all be set up for you.

Comment: i am using Gii.. But i'm new to yii and try everything myself. But there is an admin/products, but i cannot make a CRUD for that. What has to be on the dots?

Comment: The dots should stay as they are, Yii converts them to directory separators for you, so just leave them in there.

It's telling Yii to get the view located in your application views folder for the products model named _form.php, so Yii converts `application.views.products._form` for you and finds `/protected/views/products/_form.php`.

If you're using Gii, there should be a `mysite.com/products/admin` url which will allow you to make CRUD actions as an admin user (you will need to be logged in as an admin to do so)

Comment: im in over my head... It loads now, but i does not load the form nor the CSS. What did i do wrong? I hate to be noob...

Comment: if you roll back the changes you made to `/protected/views/products/admin.php`, `/protected/views/products/update.php`, and `/protected/views/products/_form.php`, the default settings created by Gii should allow you to update all models by simply going to `mysite.com/products/admin` :)

Comment: Yes i see that now, but i recently made a database driven solution for the log in, and it says i dont have permission to view that file.. How can i fix this? I have a field admin in my database that is either true or false.

Comment: You'll need to hook Yii up to your DB for login, here's a good guide on one way to do it: [Custom Authentication using the Yii Framework](http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/07/custom-authentication-using-the-yii-framework/). Hope that helps!

Comment: i will check that out and will let you know if it works or not ;) Thanks so far!

Comment: Thanks Stu, it worked, it wasn't in the tutorial you mentioned but http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/14/yii-framework-access-control-lists/